# Query XML file with LINQ in C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

i have a LINQ query for my XML file and it looks like this

```
  IEnumerable<XElement> c = from cli in xEl.Elements(ns + "client") 
                                      where cli.Element(ns+"ID").Value == (((Client)cComboBox.SelectedItem).Id +"")
                                      select cli;
```

it works fine..
Next i want to iterate that data so i do this

```
           foreach (XElement el in c)
           {

           }
```

my xml file looks like this

```
 <client>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <name>Andrej</name>
```

through that iteration, i want to extract clients values (id -> **1**, name -> **Andrej**)

my guess was to put `el.Element("name").Value` in the middle of the loop, but that doesn't work...
oh and btw: i'm doing this in C#..

What do i do?

btw2: as you can see i'm new to linq so i think i'm way off track with this one...

Any help would be appriciated!!
TNX!

Comment: sorry just to be clear do you want to get the elements which have an id = 1 or an id => 1 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I use this code:

```
  public void Run()
  {
      string fileToLoad = this.GetType().Name + ".xml";

      XElement root = XElement.Load(fileToLoad);

      var selected = from cli in root.Elements("client")
          where cli.Element("ID").Value == "1"
          select cli;

      System.Console.WriteLine("Selected:");
      foreach (var d in selected)
          Console.WriteLine("{0}", d.ToString());

      System.Console.WriteLine("\nitems:");
      foreach (var d in selected)
      {
          Console.WriteLine("id: {0}", d.Element("ID"));
      }
  }
```

And this source data:

```
<root>
  <client>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <name>Andrej</name>
  </client>
  <client>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <name>William</name>
  </client>
  <client>
    <ID>3</ID>
    <name>Kate</name>
  </client>
</root>
```

Then... I get this result:

```
Selected:
<client>
  <ID>1</ID>
  <name>Andrej</name>
</client>

items:
id: <ID>1</ID>
```

Answer (score 1):

you could do it in one statement. I'm paraphrasing your statement. Only the select really changes.

```
    var nameIdList = (from cli in client
where cli.ID == ID
select new { id=cli.ID, name=cli.name }).ToList();
```

Comment: Also I had an issue where I had XmlNodes and needed to convert to XmlElements.  Here is a good link for how to add this to your Extensions class.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2008/12/22/convert-xelement-to-xmlnode-and-convert-xmlnode-to-xelement.aspx