# Select all decedents/child nodes based on attribute value of main node.

Tags: c#

I am trying to extract block of xml based on attribute value.
Here is my xml looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<HelperKey>
 <HardwareType Module="1234">
  <m2MainHelperKey>F1DF15D4D1F5D3</m2MainHelperKey>
  <m2LowerHelperKey>ER66T4T4R5T4R</m2LowerHelperKey>
  <m2UpperHelperKey>4VXC4V5C54VC5</m2UpperHelperKey>
 </HardwareType>
 <HardwareType Module="AB45">
  <m2MainHelperKey>F1DF15FGFD4D1F5D3</m2MainHelperKey>
  <m2LowerHelperKey>ERTRTRR66T4T4R5T4R</m2LowerHelperKey>
  <m2UpperHelperKey>4VXC4FDFDFDV5C54VC5</m2UpperHelperKey>
 </HardwareType>
</HelperKey>
```

How I can select all the nodes in HardwareType based on Module value, e.g. if user provide Module 1234 following need to be selected

```
<HardwareType Module="1234">
 <m2MainHelperKey>F1DF15D4D1F5D3</m2MainHelperKey>
 <m2LowerHelperKey>ER66T4T4R5T4R</m2LowerHelperKey>
 <m2UpperHelperKey>4VXC4V5C54VC5</m2UpperHelperKey>
</HardwareType>
```

Here is some sample code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        string helpKey = HelpKey("1234", "m2LowerHelperKey");
}

string HelpKey(string module, string helperKeyName) {

        var xmlLoadfullPath = @"C:\_Codebase\Hardware\test.xml";
        var doc = XDocument.Load(xmlLoadfullPath);
        var dataid = doc.Descendants("HelperKey").Elements();

        //Write code below to select, If user passes "1234" select 

        //<HardwareType Module="1234">
        //<m2MainHelperKey>F1DF15D4D1F5D3</m2MainHelperKey>
        //<m2LowerHelperKey>ER66T4T4R5T4R</m2LowerHelperKey>
        //<m2UpperHelperKey>4VXC4V5C54VC5</m2UpperHelperKey>
        //</HardwareType>

        //Write code below to get specfic key value based on user input e.g. helperKeyName = "m2LowerHelperKey"
        //return this value -> ER66T4T4R5T4R

        var helpKey = "";

        return helpKey;
    }
```

Comment: Have you considered query with LINQ (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990953/c-sharp-querying-an-xml-document, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5831919/query-xml-file-with-linq-in-c-sharp) or with XPath (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308960.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use linq for this:

```
var hardware1234 = doc.Elements("HardwareType").
    Where(attribute => attribute.Name.LocalName.Equals("Module") 
    && attribute.Value != null && attribute.Value.Equals("1234"));
```

In short, this says:

"Give me all Elements Named Hardware where they have an Attribute named Module with a non null value of 1234."

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select just HardwareType element with module=1234, you can try this:

```
doc.Root.Elements("HardwareType").Where(e => e.Attribute("Module").ToString() == "1234");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"xmlfile1.xml");
        //get all elements for certain attribute
        var q = doc.Descendants("HardwareType").Where(c => (string) c.Attribute("Module") == "1234");

        foreach (var x in q.Elements())            
            Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}    value: {1}",x.Name , x.Value);  

        //get one element by name
        var el = q.Elements("m2LowerHelperKey").FirstOrDefault().Value;
        Console.WriteLine(el);
```

[Try It](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3luo0b)

Result:

```
    Name: m2MainHelperKey    value: F1DF15D4D1F5D3
    Name: m2LowerHelperKey    value: ER66T4T4R5T4R
    Name: m2UpperHelperKey    value: 4VXC4V5C54VC5
    ER66T4T4R5T4R
```

Comment: Spot on!, Thanks Hassan!